# Rounding errors in Pandas merge

Tags: python, floating-point

I noticed that Python rounded floating numbers after merging 2 dataframes and I was wondering if somebody knows how to disable this function.
The original dataframe had value 0.0533903000132149 and after merging this value became 0.0533903. Last 11 digits were cut off, and this causes significant rounding errors in calculations.

Does somebody know how to merge 2 dataframes without changing the original values?

Comment: Hey, could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) of the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: I am not sure I understood you

Comment: This means: provide a dataset and code that, when ran, demonstrate the rounding error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting your numerical columns into `object` datatypes (strings), before merging. In that way you will maintain all the values.

PS: Remember that `float` datatypes are not meant to be precise.